# PHP Regex: How to replace rel=stylesheet to rel=preload?

Tags: php, css, regex

I need to replace rel tag. Original code:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Necessary code:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" />
<noscript><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" /></noscript>
```

Comment: And what did you try to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a regular expression will seem a simpler solution, but it may hide a lot of pitfalls. In this case I would use DOM to make the necessary changes.

```
$html = '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//link[@rel="stylesheet"]') as $link) {
    // Insert a copy of link inside the <noscript>
    $noscript = $dom->createElement('noscript');
    $noscript->appendChild($link->cloneNode(true));
    $link->parentNode->insertBefore($noscript, $link->nextSibling);

    // Modify the link attributes
    $link->setAttribute('rel', 'preload');
    $link->setAttribute('as', 'style');
    $link->setAttribute('onload', "this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'");
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The above outputs:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"></noscript>
```